# executing python script from a node.js

Tags: python, node.js

I am trying to run a python a script which will update my elasticsearch data base, from a server which is implemented in node.js. My python script requires a csv files to read. though the csv file is present it is giving me this error(shown in image[image: error])

Comment: _"File link_myntra_blazers.csv does not exist"_. Seems to be self-explanatory.

Comment: I think you will need to specify the directory relative to where your `Node` script is running from, rather than the `Python` one.

Comment: did the specified csv file exists in folder where python script is placed?

Comment: @KarthikeyanKR yes the csv is present

Comment: if so then please try specifying the file name with path, eg: etc/folder/file.csv

Comment: @JCollerton thanks man it worked

Comment: @nishantkumar No problem man, just accept the answer when you can :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will need to specify the filepaths relative to where your `Node` script is running from, rather than the `Python` one.

So if you have file structure:

```
- app.js
- /PythonFolder
   - script.py
   - data.csv
```

You will need to call the Python using whatever the equivalent to:

```
python script.py PythonFolder/data.csv
```

is from `Node`.